# how to convert json to html with maximum optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have some json array Data which have hundred of objects with data structure similar to following

```
var json = [{"id":"123","name":"user"},{"id":"124","name":"user2"},{"id":"125","name":"user4"}]
```

I am creating `dropdown` using this data (`ul` and `li`) by using following function

```js
var newhtml = $("<div/>");
json.forEach(function (e) {
  newhtml.append('<li>'+e.name+'</li>');
});
$('ul').append(newhtml.html());
```

This is **working fine** but the problem is if `json data` goes near thousand it slows down. 
I already googled and found few ways which includes:

- Avoid appending `li` to `ul` every time. So I append only once after `forEach` loop. It optimize things to not that much.

Now my question is **How to create html using json data with optimized way ?**

Comment: Is there much use in displaying 1000+ items at once?  Can you break them down & show on demand - autocomplete search, clicking a first letter link?  If not pushing each into an array, joining to get an HTML string then setting html()/innerHTML once would be faster.

Comment: Using for-loop and native methods (= no jQuery) might speed up things a bit. But if there's a ton of new HTML to add to the DOM, there's not much you can do, it will take some time from browser to parse it all, if you want to append it all in a single chunk.

Comment: use web worker and append data in chunks...let say 500 each time...by listening message event

Comment: actually i want to append all data at once and option to select one of them and i will also give user option to search

Comment: @AnkushJain i will try to use web worker

Comment: 1000 items is far too many for a user to visually filter in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be faster if you don't create the elements until the end. Create the raw HTML first and generate the elements last.

```
var list = json.map(function(user){
  return '<li>' + user.name + '</li>';
});

$('<div/>').html( list.join('') ).appendTo('ul');
```

As @Kannan J pointed out, it's even faster if you skip the `join`.

```
var html = json.reduce(function(str, user){
  return str += '<li>' + user.name + '</li>';
}, '');

$('<div/>').html( html ).appendTo('ul');
```

Comment: since performance is concern, do we need map and join to do 2 traversals, you could do one pass with for iteration to concatenate in one go.

Comment: `div` is used only for storing markup, it is not actually appended to ul

Comment: Working fine thnks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the full list of `li` in `DocumentFragment` and after the loop finishes add it to the DOM. Another solution would be to hold the list of `li` in `DocumentFragment` and add it to the DOM in parts, for that case you have to check where is the scroller, something like a infiti-scroll, where new content is added when you reach the bottom of the page.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
json.forEach(function (e) {
    var li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerText = e.name;
    fragment.appendChild(li)
}
ul.appendChild(fragment);
```

Example with scroll:

```
var next = 50;
var ul = document.getElementById('ul');
ul.addEventListener('scroll', function(ev) {
   var a = ev.target.scrollTop;
   var b = ev.target.scrollHeight - ev.target.clientHeight;

   if((a / b) > 0.9) {
      //add next part of li's to the ul
      var part = document.createDocumentFragment();
      var start = next;
      next += next;
      [].slice.call(fragment.children, start, next).map(function(li) { part.appendChild(li); });
      ul.appendChild(part)
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this way

```
var json = [];
var length = 100000;
while(length--){
   json.push({id: length, name: length});
}
var time = new Date().getTime();
var dropdown = document.createElement('select');
json.forEach(function(item){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = item.name;
    option.value = item.id;
    dropdown.appendChild(option);
})
console.log(new Date().getTime() - time)
```

As I see 100000 elements take less than 2 sec, 10000 around 180 mcs

Comment: `option` elements don't have `innerHTML`.

Comment: prooflink, please.

Comment: @degr i dont think this will help me a lot  since it almost using the same way

Comment: @Teemu cool, please read about OOP and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: @Rakesh Soni Not sure. Your example contain additional abstraction layers from jquery and html parsing.

Comment: @degr Why, Node is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: @Teemu please look HTMLOptionElement inheritance tree

Comment: Still don't get your point, Node doesn't have `innerHTML` property either ..?

Comment: HTMLOptionElement inherits from HTMLElement, HTMLElement inherits from Element, Element inhertirs from Node. Node contain innerHTML. So, HTMLOptionElement contain innerHTML property from Node.

Comment: Accoring to MDN, [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) doesn't contain `innerHTML` property. Thought many browsers return the `option.text` when getting `innerHTML`, it is not a standard property in `option`.

Comment: The real problem is probably that the OP doesn't have options, nor a select, but an unordered list ?

Comment: @Teemu, sorry, Element contain innerHTML property, not Node.

Comment: @adeneo think there is no difference. THEtheChad solution work much faster.

Comment: Ok, please provide example where `document.createElement('option').innerHTML  = "10"` will not work.

Comment: Any, if you've a browser old enough, just a couple of years, it doesn't have to be an ancient IE.

Comment: In modern browsers it may lead to unexpected results. If for some reason you want to show a tag in an option, setting its `innerHTML` will strip the tags off from the string. `text` will preserve the tags too.

Comment: Unexpected results will happen in case if you pass html tags, because browser delegate option rendering to operation system. Think, it will omit html tags, and show text only. In this sample we have strings, so it will work perfectly in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option - building HTML then updating the DOM once:

```
var buffer = []
$.each(json, function(key, value) {
  buffer.push('<li>' + value.name + '</li>');
});
$('ul').append(buffer.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever speed is an issue:

1. Use simple `for` loops instead of `forEach`
2. Don't concatenate strings with `+` in loops. Instead, add items to an array and join them

Example:

```
var newHtml = [];
for(var j=0, jsonLen=json.length; j<jsonLen; j++){
    newHtml.push('<li>'+json[j].name+'</li>')
}
$('ul').append(newHtml.join(''));
```

From my test, its about 6x faster than your solution. For 10.000 items, duration was reduced from 453ms to 77ms. ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zohalexix/hgLevLb8/1/))

*However, as Alex K. suggested, you should avoid generating thousand elements at once. Besides the performance issue its not user-friendly either. I recommend finding another solution such as generating elements while user scrolls or making him use a search/autocomplete function.*

Answer (score 0):

Iterate once, add to simple string and insert one shot

```html
var options = "";
for (var i = 0 ; i < json.length; i++) {
   options += "<li>" + json[i].name + "</li>"
}
$('ul').append(options);
```